# Use python regex substitution with groups to get the replaced characters

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I'm looking for a way to get the grouped characters re.sub() has substituted from a string. So in e.g. this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
sentence="This is whatever. Foo"

# remove punctuation mark
new_sentence = re.sub('([\.,:;])', '', sentence)

removed_punctuation_mark = ??????????????

print(removed_punctuation_mark)
```

... how do I get the removed dot? There's re.subn() which would only show me, that one character was removed, but not which one.

Or to explain it in another way, do in python what this perl script does:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$sentence = "This is whatever. Foo";

# remove punctuation mark
$sentence =~ s/([\.,:;])//;

# first group of () in regex above
$removed_punctuation_mark = $1;    

print "$removed_punctuation_mark\n";
```

Of course I could first use re.search and group() followed by re.sub but I would have to repeat the regex, not very elegant.

Comment: what is `removed_punctuation_mark` ?

Comment: You'll want to pass `count=1` if you only want the first occurrence replaced. If you want all occurrences replaced, do you want them as a string, or as a list? In this example, you're removing the punctuation, do you need a solution that also works with an actual replacement?

Comment: @ratnesh that's explained both in the text and in the Perl example, it's the removed punctuation (in the example below, specifically the first replacement).

Comment: The replacement parameter to `re.sub()` can be a function, which is passed the match object.  It can extract whatever data it wants from this (I think `match.group(0)` is the full match), append it to a global list (or whatever else you want to do with this information, then return `""` as the replacement text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @jasonharper suggested in his comment:

```
import re

replacements = []


def replacement(x):
    replacements.append(x.group(1))
    return ''


sentence = 'This is whatever. Foo'
new_sentence = re.sub(r'([\.,:;])', replacement, sentence)

print(new_sentence, replacements)
```

This is probably what you're looking for. `x` is a match object, so it will have all the groups and other information about the match - you can get anything from it, the example grabs the first group, since that's what has the punctuation mark in your regex.